# SameSite cookie in Java application

Tags: java, cookies, csrf, flags

Do you know any Java cookie implementation which allows to set a custom flag for cookie, like `SameSite=strict`? It seems that [`javax.servlet.http.Cookie`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) has a strictly limited set of flags which can be added.

Comment: Set the header based on the servlet Cookie object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668961/how-to-set-samesite-attribute

Comment: It could be configured in code. For Spring Boot see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998367/same-site-cookie-in-spring-security/60860531#60860531

Comment: There are many solutions, based on Filters and HTTPHandlers, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697449/how-to-enable-samesite-for-jsessionid-cookie/51576089#51576089

Comment: check this one which used GenericFilterBean / temporary redirect request to solve the same kind of issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939078/how-to-set-samesite-and-secure-attribute-to-jsessionid-cookie/63939775#63939775

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I am not a JEE expert, but I think that because that cookie property is a somewhat new invention, you cannot expect it to be present in Java EE 7 interfaces or implementations. The `Cookie` class is missing a setter for generic properties, as it seems. But instead of adding the cookie to your `HttpServletResponse` via

```java
response.addCookie(myCookie)
```

you can simply set the corresponding HTTP header field via

```java
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "key=value; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict")
```

---

**Update:** Thanks to *@mwyrzyk* for pointing out that `setHeader()` overwrites all existing headers of the same name. So if you happen have other `Set-Cookie` headers in your response already, of course you would use `addHeader()` with the same parameters instead.

---

**Update:** Starting with Jakarta Servlet API, generic `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` methods have been added to the [`Cookie`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/http/cookie#setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) class.

Comment: Why the downvote? According to StackOverflow regulations, downvotes are reserved for sloppy answers of very low quality showing a significant lack of research effort or knowledge. At time of writing this, I was so far the only person talking to the OP and searching for a workaround, because what he wants is currently impossible. I even explained why it does not work the way he wishes. Even if you do not like my suggestion, you should not downvote it. Instead, you could provide a better solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that using `setHeader()` method will remove all previous headers with the same name so I had to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50704516/7280032)

Comment: is it your solution valid for jsp pages? I put your snippet inside `<% %>` but I get this error: `Cookie “JSESSIONID” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute`

Comment: @HoseinAqajani, please ask a new question, describing your situation in a reproducible way, then link to this answer from there. I have never used JSP and cannot answer your question anyway.

Comment: Can you possibly elaborate on "key=value" in the sample code?  It just looks odd to have key=value in that string.  Just don't want to blindy use this snippet.

Comment: `key` is the cookie's name, `value` is its value.

Comment: work for new version chrome. Tested with old version 50++ chrome, not working. It will not add into chrome cookie.

Comment: @PanadolChong, this is about server-side and Java, not about specific browsers. I never had any problems with this. Besides, the current Chrome version is 90, why are you testing with 50? [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) you can see that this feature was introduced in Chrome 51, so it is no surprise that it does not work before then.

Comment: @kriegaex, thanks for the comment. well, its not developer want to test with version 50. But there is a client using version 50, and no choice we have to do and fix it, haha

Comment: Well, if the browser is so old that it does not even know what a same-site cookie is, of course it will not have any effect, even if the server configures it correctly. But this is really off-topic here. Good luck to you.

Comment: I ended up creating my own extensible Cookie class that has the SameSite attribute built in.  It even has a send(final HttpServletResponse response) method for sending the cookie data using response.addHeader(), as per the above answer.

Answer (score 20):

If you happen to use Spring Framework you can take advantage of [ResponseCookie](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseCookie.html) class. Ex:

```
final ResponseCookie responseCookie = ResponseCookie
        .from("<my-cookie-name>", "<my-cookie-value-here>")
        .secure(true)
        .httpOnly(true)
        .path("/auth")
        .maxAge(12345)
        .sameSite("Lax")
        .build();
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, responseCookie.toString());
```

**Disclamer**: The flags and their values are provided just as an example for the class' API.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't wanna update all your code, you can also achieve same by one line config using Apache or Nginx configuration(or any other HTTP server/proxy that you are using)

#### 1 Setting SameSite cookies using Apache configuration

You can add the following line to your Apache configuration

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=Lax"
```

and this will update all your cookies with `SameSite=Lax` flag

See more here: https://blog.giantgeek.com/?p=1872

#### 2 Setting SameSite cookies using Nginx configuration

```
location / {
    # your usual config ...
    # hack, set all cookies to secure, httponly and samesite (strict or lax)
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict";
}
```

Same here, this also will update all your cookies with `SameSite=Lax` flag

See more here: https://serverfault.com/questions/849888/add-samesite-to-cookies-using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy

Comment: Any idea what might stop approach 1 from working in a ProxyPass situation?  That line does edit `Set-Cookie` headers that are inserted with e.g. `Header always add Set-Cookie "foo-bar"` in the apache config, but does not modify headers originally in the proxied response.

Answer (score 13):

As of today (24.01.20) `servlet-api` does not let to set `sameSite` attribute to the cookie. BTW there is an ongoing ticket ([LINK](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/servlet-api/pull/271)) which will release a new (5.0 or 5.1 `servlet-api`).

**Option 1:** You are not in a hurry and can wait for `servlet-api` version, where `Cookie` class and `SessionCookieConfig` class have dedicated methods to set `sameSite` attribute.

**Option 2:** You are using an old version of `servlet-api` (e.g. 3.1), consequently old version of Tomcat (e.g. I am having current situation now). It means even when community releases `servlet-api` with `sameSite` support, you can not immediately update you version, because it can be too risky to update couple of major versions.
In this case we have found a solution.
There is a `Cookie Processor Component`[LINK](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/cookie-processor.html) in Tomcat, which

> The CookieProcessor element represents the component that parses received cookie headers into javax.servlet.http.Cookie objects accessible through HttpServletRequest.getCookies() and converts javax.servlet.http.Cookie objects added to the response through HttpServletResponse.addCookie() to the HTTP headers returned to the client.

The usage of this processor is quite straight forward. Inside of context.xml:

```
<Context>
    ...
    <CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="none"/>
</Context>
```

In this case default implementation of processor is used (`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor`), but you can specify any other within an `CookieProcessor` attribute `className`.

Answer (score 9):

Jetty server version `9.4.26.v20200117` allows for setting the `SameSite` attribute on the cookie. I had to do some digging around but this works.

```java
import static org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCookie.SAME_SITE_STRICT_COMMENT;

...

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("my-cookie", "some-value");
cookie.setMaxAge(120); // age in seconds
cookie.setSecure(true);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setComment(SAME_SITE_STRICT_COMMENT);

response.addCookie(cookie);
```

The `addCookie()` method on jetty servers's `Response` object does a check on the comment to add the `SameSite` attribute.

Comment: That is comfortable! I love Jetty

Comment: how we can do in the older version of Jetty like 6.0?

Comment: Works in Jetty 11.0.8 as well.  Sweet!  This is a hack, but probably the best solution for jetty users, even though it creates very mild vendor lock-in.

Comment: @jatinGoyal if your web server doesn't have this hack, you should probably tweak the response header directly as best you can.  Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106260/1128668 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60611228/1128668 though both have potential data sanitization or character encoding issues.  I recommend you upgrade to at least Jetty 9.

Answer (score 9):

If you have existing code, no doubt you've used the java servlet Cookie object.  We certainly have, so we wanted the least disruptive option.  @kriegaex's answer is clean and concise, but is basically hard coding the cookie and doesn't reuse the cookie object.  To expand on his answer, we wrote this function to handle the same site functionality, while at the same time, maintaining the existing Cookie object functionality.  This answer is intended to be used in cases where you need to add multiple cookies on your response object, without making changes to existing cookies that may already be on the headers. The other option of course is to write a new cookie class and extend the functionality, but that requires even more changes to existing code than what we've come up with here.

Note that with this solution, only one line of existing code (per cookie) changes in order to add the same site functionality.

Sample usage:

```
// Existing code that doesn't change:   
Cookie cookie1=new Cookie("cookie1",Util.encodeURL(id));
cookie1.setHttpOnly(false);
cookie1.setPath("/");

Cookie cookie2=new Cookie("cookie2",Util.encodeURL(id));
cookie2.setHttpOnly(false);
cookie2.setPath("/");

// Old Code that is replaced by new code
// httpResponse.addCookie(cookie1);
// httpResponse.addCookie(cookie2);

// New Code - see static helper class below
HttpService.addCookie(httpResponse, cookie1, "none");
HttpService.addCookie(httpResponse, cookie2, "Strict");
```

Example response headers when using cURL:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
< Set-Cookie: cookie1=f871c026e8eb418c9c612f0c7fe05b08; path=/; SameSite=none; secure
< Set-Cookie: cookie2=51b405b9487f4487b50c80b32eabcc24; path=/; SameSite=Strict; secure
< Server: WildFly/9
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: image/png
< Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2020 01:55:37 GMT
```

And finally, the static helper class:

```
public class HttpService {
    private static final FastDateFormat expiresDateFormat= FastDateFormat.getInstance("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));


    public static void addCookie(HttpServletResponse response, Cookie cookie, String sameSite) {

        StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder(64+cookie.getValue().length());

        c.append(cookie.getName());
        c.append('=');
        c.append(cookie.getValue());

        append2cookie(c,"domain",   cookie.getDomain());
        append2cookie(c,"path",     cookie.getPath());
        append2cookie(c,"SameSite", sameSite);

        if (cookie.getSecure()) {
            c.append("; secure");
        }
        if (cookie.isHttpOnly()) {
            c.append("; HttpOnly");
        }
        if (cookie.getMaxAge()>=0) {
            append2cookie(c,"Expires", getExpires(cookie.getMaxAge()));
        }

        response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", c.toString());
    }

    private static String getExpires(int maxAge) {
        if (maxAge<0) {
            return "";
        }
        Calendar expireDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        expireDate.setTime(new Date());
        expireDate.add(Calendar.SECOND,maxAge);

        return expiresDateFormat.format(expireDate);
    }

    private static void append2cookie(StringBuilder cookie, String key, String value) {
        if (key==null || 
                value==null || 
                key.trim().equals("") 
                || value.trim().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        cookie.append("; ");
        cookie.append(key);
        cookie.append('=');
        cookie.append(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your code! Please take care: if a cookie has no Secure flag and SameSite is set, it will still be ignored (https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/). So I had to wrap "append2cookie(c,"SameSite", sameSite)" with if(cookie.getSecure)

Comment: While this is a useful answer, note that the proposed code does not properly escape the cookie name, value, domain, path,… etc. So some extra work is needed to make it safer to use in a general context

Comment: MaxAge and Expiration are not exact synonyms.  MaxAge takes precedence and is measured from the time the HTTP response is received.  "When an Expires date is set, the deadline is relative to the client the cookie is being set on."  Presumably in the client's time zone.  I would prefer MaxAge myself.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the listed solutions for using [`javax.servlet.http.Cookie`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) to set the `SameSite=strict` attribute, but none of them worked.

However, this way worked for me, using [`javax.servlet.http.Cookie`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) (JRE 1.8 + JBOSS 7.X) :

```java
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
path = path.concat("SameSite=Strict;");
cookie.setPath(path);
```

That's it. tested on

- Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Microsoft Edge Version 81.0.416.68 (Official build) (64-bit)
- Firefox 75.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work if you have a path e.g. path `/ SameSite=None;` results in "An invalid path ... was specified for this cookie".

Comment: I would modify this to 
```Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
    path = path.concat("; SameSite=Strict;");
    cookie.setPath(path);```

Comment: it doesn't work under tomcat 8.60, it has Rfc6265CookieProcessor and inside there's a validation for char ';' in a path. Same for the cookie value

Answer (score 3):

For using Spring Boot with Tomcat, this has been answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860531/400048).

In summary, set the attribute in the Tomcat config. This is global, all cookies will then have `SameSite` attribute set.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Bean
  public TomcatContextCustomizer sameSiteCookiesConfig() {
    return context -> {
        final Rfc6265CookieProcessor cookieProcessor = new Rfc6265CookieProcessor();
        cookieProcessor.setSameSiteCookies(SameSiteCookies.NONE.getValue());
        context.setCookieProcessor(cookieProcessor);
    };
  }
```

Comment: This really added the header in my case, thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

I found that our cookies which were being created on a successful return were not changed by "Header edit" or "Header always edit".  Apparently apache has two buckets of cookies - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053741/httpd-duplicate-access-control-allow-origin-with-header-always-set/44724866#44724866)

What did work for me was

```
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=Lax"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using spring boot or spring session.

for more details about the solution
[Samesite for jessessionId cookie can be set only from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069650/samesite-for-jessessionid-cookie-can-be-set-only-from-response/64314117#64314117)

```
        package com.cookie.example.filters.cookie;


  import com.google.common.net.HttpHeaders;
  import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
  import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
  import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;

  import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
  import javax.servlet.*;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.List;

  /**
   * Implementation of an HTTP filter {@link Filter} which which allow customization of {@literal Set-Cookie} header.
   * customization is delegated to implementations of {@link CookieHeaderCustomizer}
   */
  public class CookieHeaderCustomizerFilter extends DelegatingFilterProxy implements InitializingBean {

    private final List<CookieHeaderCustomizer> cookieHeaderCustomizers;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws ServletException {
      super.afterPropertiesSet();
      if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cookieHeaderCustomizers)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cookieHeaderCustomizers is mandatory");
      }
    }

    public CookieHeaderCustomizerFilter(final List<CookieHeaderCustomizer> cookieHeaderCustomizers) {
      this.cookieHeaderCustomizers = cookieHeaderCustomizers;
    }

    public CookieHeaderCustomizerFilter() {
      this.cookieHeaderCustomizers = Collections.emptyList();
    }


    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void destroy() {
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

      if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        throw new ServletException("Request is not an instance of HttpServletRequest");
      }

      if (!(response instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
        throw new ServletException("Response is not an instance of HttpServletResponse");
      }

      chain.doFilter(request, new CookieHeaderResponseWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse)response ));

    }


    /**
     * An implementation of the {@link HttpServletResponse} which customize {@literal Set-Cookie}
     */
    private class CookieHeaderResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper{

      @Nonnull private final HttpServletRequest request;

      @Nonnull private final HttpServletResponse response;


      public CookieHeaderResponseWrapper(@Nonnull final HttpServletRequest req, @Nonnull final HttpServletResponse resp) {
        super(resp);
        this.request = req;
        this.response = resp;

      }

      /** {@inheritDoc} */
      @Override
      public void sendError(final int sc) throws IOException {
        applyCustomizers();
        super.sendError(sc);
      }

      /** {@inheritDoc} */
      @Override
      public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        applyCustomizers();
        return super.getWriter();
      }

      /** {@inheritDoc} */
      @Override
      public void sendError(final int sc, final String msg) throws IOException {
        applyCustomizers();
        super.sendError(sc, msg);
      }

      /** {@inheritDoc} */
      @Override
      public void sendRedirect(final String location) throws IOException {
        applyCustomizers();
        super.sendRedirect(location);
      }

      /** {@inheritDoc} */
      @Override
      public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        applyCustomizers();
        return super.getOutputStream();
      }

      private void applyCustomizers(){

        final Collection<String> cookiesHeaders = response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);

        boolean firstHeader = true;

        for (final String cookieHeader : cookiesHeaders) {

          if (StringUtils.isBlank(cookieHeader)) {
            continue;
          }

          String customizedCookieHeader = cookieHeader;

          for(CookieHeaderCustomizer cookieHeaderCustomizer : cookieHeaderCustomizers){

            customizedCookieHeader = cookieHeaderCustomizer.customize(request, response, customizedCookieHeader);

          }

          if (firstHeader) {
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,customizedCookieHeader);
            firstHeader=false;
          } else {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, customizedCookieHeader);
          }

        }

      }

    }

  }



  /**
   * Implement this interface and inject add it to {@link SameSiteCookieHeaderCustomizer}
   */
  public interface CookieHeaderCustomizer {
    String customize(@Nonnull final HttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull final HttpServletResponse response, @Nonnull final String cookieHeader);
  }


    package com.cookie.example.filters.cookie;

      import org.slf4j.Logger;
      import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

      import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  /**
   *Add SameSite attribute if not already exist
   *SameSite attribute value is defined by property "cookie.sameSite"
   */
  public class SameSiteCookieHeaderCustomizer implements CookieHeaderCustomizer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SameSiteCookieHeaderCustomizer.class);

    private static final String SAME_SITE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME ="SameSite";

    private static final String SECURE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME="Secure";

    private final SameSiteValue sameSiteValue;

    public SameSiteCookieHeaderCustomizer(SameSiteValue sameSiteValue) {
      this.sameSiteValue = sameSiteValue;
    }


    @Override
    public String customize(@Nonnull final HttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull final HttpServletResponse response, @Nonnull final String cookieHeader) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cookieHeader);
      if (!cookieHeader.contains(SAME_SITE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)) {
        sb.append("; ").append(SAME_SITE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME).append("=").append(sameSiteValue.value);
      }
      if(SameSiteValue.None == sameSiteValue && !cookieHeader.contains(SECURE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)){
        sb.append("; ").append(SECURE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }

    public enum SameSiteValue{

      /**
       * Send the cookie for 'same-site' requests only.
       */
      Strict("Strict"),
      /**
       * Send the cookie for 'same-site' requests along with 'cross-site' top
       * level navigations using safe HTTP methods (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and TRACE).
       */
      Lax("Lax"),
      /**
       * Send the cookie for 'same-site' and 'cross-site' requests.
       */
      None("None");

      /** The same-site attribute value.*/
      private String value;

      /**
       * Constructor.
       *
       * @param attrValue the same-site attribute value.
       */
      SameSiteValue(@Nonnull final String attrValue) {
        value = attrValue;
      }

      /**
       * Get the same-site attribute value.
       *
       * @return Returns the value.
       */
      public String getValue() {
        return value;
      }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

ravinder5 did implement this and open sourced it: [CookieHeader](https://github.com/ravinder5/cookie-header)

Sample usage:

```
import com.tgt.egs.auth.cookie.CookieHeader;
...

CookieHeader.createSetCookieHeader(cookieName, cookieValue, domain, path, sameSite, secure, httpOnly, expiry);
```