# Setting jsessonid cookie to SameSite=Strict attribute in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, cookies

What is the spring-boot configuration to set jsessionId cookie as SameSite=Strict.

JsessionId need to add SameSite=Strict or existing cookie not new cookie generation.Is it support?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same-Site cookie in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998367/same-site-cookie-in-spring-security)

Comment: yes, but want the SameSite=Strict for jsessionId cookies

Comment: Check this solution. You might able to solve the problem with a little tweak. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64558083/4423695

Answer (score 5):

I used Rfc6265CookieProcessor to configure SameSite flag in the spring boot application as a workaround.

**build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    ...
}
```

**Config in the main class:**

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            Rfc6265CookieProcessor rfc6265CookieProcessor = new Rfc6265CookieProcessor();
            rfc6265CookieProcessor.setSameSiteCookies("Strict");
            context.setCookieProcessor(rfc6265CookieProcessor);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: The `Context` class you need to import is from `org.apache.catalina.Context`

Answer (score 2):

With Undertow 2.1.0.Final and later you can do it like this:

```
public static final String COOKIE_PATTERN = "JSESSIONID";

@Bean
public UndertowServletWebServerFactory undertowServletWebServerFactory() {
    UndertowServletWebServerFactory undertow = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
    
    undertow.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(
            deploymentInfo -> deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper(
                    handler -> new SameSiteCookieHandler(handler, CookieSameSiteMode.STRICT.name(), COOKIE_PATTERN)
            ));
    
    return undertow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported, according to [this open issue in Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4341).