# how to same site None or not seame site url cookie chrome http connect

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, google-chrome, spring-security, samesite

I am getting

> Developers: Get Ready for New SameSite = None; Secure Cookie
>   Settings

Did not prepare for, there was an error.

I want to set it up so that I can access it before I prepare.

But I don't even know how.

Backend

```
Kotiln 1.2.71
SpringBoot 2.1.6
I am using spring security 2.9.2.
```

Front end

```
Typescript 3.5.2 React 16.8.6
```

Let me know if you need more

Note that the front end is on AWS S3, the backend is on an AWS EC2 Linux server.

And I use http. No security.

Refer to the site below to get the desired header value,
Cookies (session) are not saved.

```
sameSize = None
```

[Same-Site cookie in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998367/same-site-cookie-in-spring-security)

What should I do?

Any hope for beginners would be appreciated.

Also, I would be grateful if you let me know what you need to worry about, except for processing cookies when you think about this.

Comment: Whats the problem with https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860531/548473 solution?

Comment: @GrigoryKislin Thank you. I think I can use it!

Comment: If it suit, you can also vote for it:)