# Add SameSite Property to JBoss AS7.1 Application

Tags: jboss7.x, web.xml, servlet-filters, samesite

I have an JBoss AS7.1 web application. I want to make it more secure, so i added some attributes to my web.xml.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

This ended up with:[image]

Now i want to check the "SameSite" attribute. I tried to create a servlet filter, where i set the header of my "Set-Cookie" attribute, as described under [How to set SameSite attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668961/how-to-set-samesite-attribute)
but it did not work.

Anybody knows, how to add the "SameSite" attribute to an JSF web application running on JBoss AS7.1?

Comment: Did you get it working in an almost empty web project without jsf but with a simple jsp?

Comment: Haven't tried it.

Comment: please so. If that does not work either, the question is not jsf related and you have narrowed it down

Comment: I tried it! It is NOT working. Why is the question not jsf related?

Comment: 99.9% percent of the things you configure in web.xml are not related to jsf but basic (java) web development. If it fails in the simple non-jsf application you tried, you have proof it is not jsf related

Comment: Well ok but the "sameSite" attribute IS NOT configurable in the web.xml. So i think there has to be a way to implement it somehow in a jsf related environment.

Comment: No to a java web environment